# Insert class in inheritance hierarchy (objective-c)

Tags: objective-c, inheritance

Is there ability to insert base class to inheritance hierarchy?
Here is an example:

```
@interface BaseClass // has a lot of basic functionality and interface
{...}
@end

@interface ChildClass : BaseClass // customizes BaseClass functionality
{...}
@end

@interface BaseClassEx : BaseClass // add some features to base class
{...}
@end
```

I want to have ChildClassEx that has all methods from ChildClass but is inherited from BaseClassEx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like multiple inheritance. Objective C doesn't have it.

Based on your description, I would suggest a different design pattern.

```
@class BaseUtility // has a lot of basic functionality
{...}
@end

@class BaseClass // has interface
{...}
@property BaseUtility *utility;
@end

@class ChildUtility : BaseUtility // customizes basic functionality
{...}
@end

@class BaseClassEx : BaseClass // add some features to base class
{...}
@end
```

Now you can have four kinds of things.

1. A BaseClass with a BaseUtility assigned to it, which is like your BaseClass.
2. A BaseClass with a ChildUtility assigned to it, which is like your ChildClass. It gets customized behavior and has the same interface as BaseClass.
3. A BaseClassEx with a BaseUtility assigned to it, which is like your BaseClassEx. It has extra features (extra interface I assume).
4. A BaseClassEx with a ChildUtility assigned to it, which is like the ChildClassEx that you want. It has extra features and customized functionality.

Class inheritance is the "is a" pattern. The above combines both the "is a" pattern and the "has a" pattern. To get the effect of a ChildClassEx you want, you make something that "is a" BaseClassEx, but "has a" ChildUtility.

Comment: Yes I used this kind of solution: I declare pointer to BaseUtility and initialize it in additional init method. This has some disadvantages because BaseUtility needs access to inner BaseClass data.

Comment: Consider moving the data that BaseUtility needs to access into BaseUtility. BaseUtility can have some state too. But then maybe BaseClass will also want to access that data. Sometimes you just have to create an access point in one or the other for the data.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just inherit from `ChildClass`? This inherits everything from all the super classes automatically

```
@interface BaseClassEx : ChildClass // add some features...
{...}
@end
```

Comment: In practice I have 2 child classes. Thats why if I inherit BaseClassEx from child class I need to duplicate its code (BaseClassEx1, BaseClassEx2). And this solution is not "beautiful" from design point of view.

Answer (score 0):

There's no multiple inheritance on Objective-C.  However, there are several different patterns you can use that achieve a similar effect.  As long as your BaseClassEx only adds new methods (and doesn't try to override the behaviour of existing BaseClass methods), the easiest thing is to declare a category

```
@interface BaseClass(BaseClassEx)

// new method declarations

@end

@implementtion BaseClass(BaseClassEx)

// new method definitions

@end
```

If you do this, all instances of BaseClass will have the new methods.  This works for any existing class, even things like NSString.

Comment: This will affect all classes. I dont want to change behavior of BaseClass and ChildClass.